# How does paging work with ROW_NUMBER in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have an `Employee` table that has one million records. I have following SQL for paging data in a web application. It is working fine. However what I see as an issue is - the derived table `tblEmployee` selects all records in the `Employee` table (to create the  `MyRowNumber` values).

I think, this causes selection of all records in the `Employee` table.

Does it really work so? Or is SQL Server optimized to select only the 5 records from the original `Employee` table too?

```
DECLARE @Index INT;
DECLARE @PageSize INT;

SET @Index = 3;
SET @PageSize = 5;

SELECT *  FROM
  (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID asc) as MyRowNumber,*
  FROM Employee) tblEmployee
WHERE MyRowNumber BETWEEN ( ((@Index - 1) * @PageSize )+ 1) AND @Index*@PageSize
```

Comment: See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/ and more importantly [the ensuing discussion](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An alternative to test might be:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT EmpID, k = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) FROM dbo.Emp)
SELECT e.columns
FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.Emp AS e
ON x.EmpID = e.EmpID
WHERE x.k BETWEEN (((@Index - 1) * @PageSize) + 1) AND @Index * @PageSize
ORDER BY ...;
```

Yes, you hit the table twice, but in the CTE where you scan the whole table you are only grabbing the key, not ALL of the data. But you really should look at this article:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/

And the follow-up discussion:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx

In SQL Server 2012 of course you can use the new `OFFSET` / `FETCH NEXT` syntax:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT EmpID FROM dbo.Emp
    ORDER BY EmpID
    OFFSET  @PageSize * (@Index - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT e.columns
FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.Emp AS e
ON x.EmpID = e.EmpID
ORDER BY ...;
```

I also blogged about this in more detail here:

- [SQL Server v.Next (Denali) : Using the OFFSET clause (paging)](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/10/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-the-offset-clause-paging)
- [Pagination with OFFSET / FETCH : A better way](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)

Comment: Should be noted though that OFFSET/FETCH NEXT do not offer any performance benefits over the CTE method

Comment: @Akash have you thoroughly tested this? I've observed some plan differences but did not specifically mention anything about the performance because I haven't done any extensive testing. Even if the performance is the same the syntax is slightly less cumbersome. I did blog about it here: https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/10/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-the-offset-clause-paging and here: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: Ah, you're right, theres a performance difference. I had read this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2011/11/01/my-top-5-sql-server-2012-features-by-aaron-bertrand-guest-blogger.aspx where he mentions no difference, but just saw http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/SQL11UPD03-REC-02 where he shows theres a lot of difference..  (though in the audio underemphasis the performance difference)

Answer (score 2):

Although you may not know the mechanism behind it, you could test this yourself by comparing the performance of your query to: select * from Employee.

The more recent versions of SQL Server do a pretty good job of optimizing, but it can depend on several factors.

How your ROW_NUMBER function performs is going to be driven by the Order By clause. In your example, most would guess EmpID is the primary key.

There are some *where* clauses that are so complex and/or poorly coded or indexed, you may be better off just returning the whole dataset (it's rare and can be fixed). Using BETWEEN has issues.

Before you assume it would be better to return all the rows to your application and let it figure it out, you should work on optimizing your query. Check the estimates. Ask the Query Analyzer. Test some alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is regarding row_number() but i want to add one new feature of sql server 2012. In sql server 2012 new feature OFFSET Fetch next introduced and it is very fast than row_number(). I have used it and it gives me good result hope you guys also fill same experience.

I found one example on http://blogfornet.com/2013/06/sql-server-2012-offset-use/

which is useful. Hope it will help you too for implement new features....

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it evaluates to return all rows in the original table.
SQL server optimizes.
Otherwise it will take a huge amount of time to select a million entries.
I am currently using this and it is much faster than selecting all rows.
So, sure does not get all the rows.
It is however slower than just fetching the first five rows, probably due to time taken in ordering

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @PageIndex int;
DECLARE @PageSize int;
SET @PageIndex = 4;
SET @PageSize = 5;
;With ranked AS   --- Or you can make it a view
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdentityId) AS RowNum,  *
   FROM logeventnew
)
SELECT *   --Your fields here
FROM Ranked
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
    AND (@PageIndex * @PageSize)
ORDER BY IdentityId
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer? The question was regarding *how* the paging works internally to SQL Server - i.e. what does the database engine do to fulfill the request. Unfortunately, as of now, your answer does not address the actual concern.